# MySQL/MariaDB: create a pivot table view

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot-table

Hi have this **MySQL (MariaDB)** table:

```
+----+-------+-------+---------+
| id | name  | value | user_id |
+----+-------+-------+---------+
|  1 | foo   | 40    |      10 |
|  2 | bar   | 15    |      10 |
|  3 | baz   | 390   |      10 |
|  4 | quux  | ENG   |      10 |
|  5 | waldo | 1     |      10 |
|  6 | foo   | 20    |      13 |
|  7 | bar   | 15    |      13 |
|  8 | waldo | 1     |      13 |
|  9 | baz   | 0     |      13 |
| 10 | quux  | ENG   |      13 |
| 11 | baz   | 420   |      15 |
| 12 | waldo | 1     |      15 |
| 13 | bar   | 1     |      15 |
| 14 | foo   | 5     |      15 |
| 15 | quux  | ENG   |      15 |
| 16 | waldo | 1     |      16 |
| 17 | quux  | ENG   |      16 |
| 18 | foo   | 5     |      16 |
| 19 | baz   | 0     |      16 |
| 20 | bar   | 15    |      16 |
+----+-------+-------+---------+
```

I need to get **a view like this**:

```
+---------+-----+-----+------------+-------+
| user_id | foo | bar | baz | quux | waldo |
+---------+-----+-----+------------+-------+
|      10 | 40  |  15 | 390 | ENG  |     1 |
|      13 | 20  |  15 |   0 | ENG  |     1 |
|      15 | 5   |   1 | 420 | ENG  |     1 |
|      16 | 5   |  15 |   0 | ENG  |     1 |
+---------+-----+-----+-----+------+-------+
```

I read the following articles about Pivot Tables in MySQL but I need some help in creating the correct query:

- https://riptutorial.com/mysql/example/10441/creating-a-pivot-query
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table
- https://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/
- https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Could you help me please?

Comment: Please publish what you have tried and describe what you mean by desired result(if different to that in the question)

Comment: @P.Salmon I added the articles links I read, and the desidered result is exactly what I manually composed in the second table.

Comment: All the articles seem clear if you publish what you tried we can point out where you went wrong.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: There are decent coding examples in the Q&As off tag `[pivot-table]`; review them.

Comment: For MariaDB, see See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670844/1766831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed in creating the correct query:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN name = "foo" THEN value END) "foo",
  MAX(CASE WHEN name = "bar" THEN value END) "bar",
  MAX(CASE WHEN name = "baz" THEN value END) "baz",
  MAX(CASE WHEN name = "quux" THEN value END) "quux",
  MAX(CASE WHEN name = "waldo" THEN value END) "waldo"
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a pivot table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(5),
>   `value` VARCHAR(3),
>   `user_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `name`, `value`, `user_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'foo', '40', '10'),
>   ('2', 'bar', '15', '10'),
>   ('3', 'baz', '390', '10'),
>   ('4', 'quux', 'ENG', '10'),
>   ('5', 'waldo', '1', '10'),
>   ('6', 'foo', '20', '13'),
>   ('7', 'bar', '15', '13'),
>   ('8', 'waldo', '1', '13'),
>   ('9', 'baz', '0', '13'),
>   ('10', 'quux', 'ENG', '13'),
>   ('11', 'baz', '420', '15'),
>   ('12', 'waldo', '1', '15'),
>   ('13', 'bar', '1', '15'),
>   ('14', 'foo', '5', '15'),
>   ('15', 'quux', 'ENG', '15'),
>   ('16', 'waldo', '1', '16'),
>   ('17', 'quux', 'ENG', '16'),
>   ('18', 'foo', '5', '16'),
>   ('19', 'baz', '0', '16'),
>   ('20', 'bar', '15', '16');
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>                CONCAT('MAX(IF(s.name = "', `name`,'", `value`,"")) AS ',name)
>               ) INTO @sql
> FROM table1;
>
>
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.user_id,  ', @sql, ' 
>                   FROM table1 s
>                  GROUP BY s.user_id
>                  ORDER BY s.user_id');
> SELECT @sql;
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | bar | baz | foo | quux | waldo
> ------: | :-- | :-- | :-- | :--- | :----
>      10 | 15  | 390 | 40  | ENG  | 1    
>      13 | 15  | 0   | 20  | ENG  | 1    
>      15 | 1   | 420 | 5   | ENG  | 1    
>      16 | 15  | 0   | 5   | ENG  | 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab8fabcae1a7651f5b50239531abb50b)*

Comment: This works well but will fail if 'name' is not a valid sql column name - for instance if it contains a space. I have a KVP table which contains keys such as 'Voltage Rating (DC)' which cause this method to bork.  I am trying to find a way of passing the name in backticks but have not succeeded. The keys are in an external table and I have no control over the keys used.

Comment: @Gasman change it to   `CONCAT('MAX(IF(s.name = "', `name`,'", `value`,"")) AS "',name,'"')`

Comment: Thanks! Ive also found that  ```SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
               CONCAT('MAX(IF(s.name = "', `name`,'", `value`,"")) AS ', QUOTE(`name`))
              ) INTO @sql
FROM table1;``` is a solution.

Comment: Yes that is also a solution, but the po es t is still helpful