# Joining multiple rows with same ID in one

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot

I am having trouble with an SQL query. I have two tables.

My first table:

```
+------------+-------------+---------------+
| id_mission | Some column | Other column  |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      1     |     ...     |      ...      |
|      2     |     ...     |      ...      |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
```

My second table:

```
+------------+-------------+---------+
| id_mission | id_category | points  |
+------------+-------------+---------+
|          1 |           1 |       3 |
|          1 |           2 |       4 |
|          1 |           3 |       4 |
|          1 |           4 |       8 |
|          2 |           1 |      -4 |
|          2 |           2 |       3 |
|          2 |           3 |       1 |
|          2 |           4 |      -7 |
+------------+-------------+---------+
```

And I would like to have this kind of result with my `SELECT` request

```
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
| id_mission | Some column | Other column | id_category 1 | id_category X  |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
|          1 |         ... |          ... |           ... |            ... |
|          2 |         ... |          ... |           ... |            ... |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
```

I have tried this with the first two column but it doesn't work, I also tried `GROUP_CONCAT`, it works but it's not the result I want.

```sql
SELECT m.id_mission ,mc.id_category 1,mc1.id_category 2
from mission m 
left join mission_category mc on m.id_mission = mc.id_mission 
left join mission_category mc1 on m.id_mission = mc1.id_mission
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your description of the result set is identical to the first table.  More detail and explanation is needed.

Comment: thta is a simple example how to build pivot table https://stackoverflow.com/a/62712027/5193536  if you need help you must provide example data and not only ----

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation. Assuming that you want to pivot the `points` value per category:

```
select 
    t1.*,
    max(case when t2.id_category = 1 then points end) category_1,
    max(case when t2.id_category = 2 then points end) category_2,
    max(case when t2.id_category = 3 then points end) category_3
from t1
inner join t2 on t2.id_mission = t1.id_mission
group by t1.id_mission
```

This assumes that `id_mission` is the primary key of `t1` (else, you need to enumerate the columns you want in both the `select` and `group by` clauses).