# Set alias column in a select by another select

Tags: sql, select, mariadb, alias

I need some help with mariadb queries. I'm trying to set an alias column with the result of another select.

I have 3 tables:

- Units_dimension.
- Units.
- Readings.

Units_dimension table:

| id | dimension |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | temperature |
| 2 | humidity |
| 3 | pressure |

Units table:

| id | dimension_id | unit | representation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Celsius | °C |
| 2 | 1 | Farenheit | °F |
| 3 | 1 | Kelvin | K |
| 4 | 2 | Percentage | % |
| 5 | 3 | HectoPascal | hPa |

Readings table:

| id | station_id | datetime | unit_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ESP0001 | 2022-10-31 01:00:00.000 | 1 | 23.5 |
| 2 | ESP0001 | 2022-10-31 01:00:00.000 | 4 | 79 |
| 3 | ESP0001 | 2022-10-31 01:00:00.000 | 5 | 1019.6 |
| 4 | ESP0001 | 2022-10-31 02:00:00.000 | 1 | 23.3 |
| 5 | ESP0001 | 2022-10-31 02:00:00.000 | 4 | 79 |
| 5 | ESP0001 | 2022-10-31 02:00:00.000 | 5 | 1019.6 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to get the value column in a select with alias from the unit dimension.

Example SELECT r.datetime, r.value AS (?1) FROM readings r WHERE station_id = 'ESP0001' and unit_id = ?2

?1 is temperature or humidity or pressure, etc.

?2 is the unit_id.

I tried something like that:

```sql
SELECT 
    r.datetime, 
    r.value AS (SELECT ud.dimension FROM units u LEFT JOIN unit_dimension ud ON (ud.id = u.dimension_id) WHERE u.id = 1) 
FROM readings r 
WHERE r.unit_id = 1;
```

But I have an SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=67) You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Thanks.

Comment: for such a query you need dynamic sql,

Comment: have a read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62711642/mysql-mariadb-create-a-pivot-table-view

Comment: @nbk is correct. In plain SQL, there is no way to use the value in a column for an identifier name, whether alias name, column name, or table name. "Dynamic SQL" means "write a program to create a text string containing the SQL statement you want, then run it."

Comment: maybe you can find here some inspiration: https://www.tarynpivots.com/post/how-to-rotate-rows-into-columns-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly believe You can simplify the whole query as below:

```
SELECT r.`datetime`, r.`value`, ud.`dimension`
  FROM readings r, units u, unit_dimension ud
 WHERE u.id = r.unit_id 
   AND ud.id = u.dimension_id
   AND r.station_id = 'ESP0001'
   AND r.unit_id = 1 -- Celsius
```

Comment: ge wants ti get alias of the values in a separate table Units_dimension  , not as another column

Comment: @nbk, you are right, i strongly believe it is impossible inside a simple query

Comment: Thanks for this simplification!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. I think i'll try two querys, store the resulset into a variable and them combine the result.

Finally the querys (backend api in nodejs):

The first query result returns the dimension. If the unit id is not correct the response will be 404.

```sql
SELECT ud.dimension 
FROM units u, unit_dimension ud 
WHERE ud.id = u.dimension_id 
AND u.id = ${req.params.unit_id};
```

The second query:

```sql
SELECT r.datetime, r.value AS ${dimension}, u.representation 
FROM readings r, units u, unit_dimension ud
WHERE u.id = r.unit_id 
AND ud.id = u.dimension_id
AND r.station_id = '${req.params.station_id}'
AND r.unit_id = ${req.params.unit_id};
```