# How can I convert sql query from ms access to mariadb sql

Tags: ms-access, mariadb

This is a query which uses 2 tables, one is advdep and other is paymode

advdep table :

Adv_amt
AdvDate
AdvMode

Paymode table :
PayID
Paymode

I am using crosstab query in ms access which works well (takes a lot of time!)

```
TRANSFORM Sum(advdep.Adv_Amt) AS Totals
       SELECT Year([AdvDate]) AS [Year], Sum([advdep].[Adv_Amt])\1 AS Total
       FROM advdep INNER JOIN paymode ON advdep.AdvMode = paymode.PayID
GROUP BY Year([AdvDate])
PIVOT paymode.Paymode;
```

I need to convert this into mariadb view

```
SELECT *
    FROM
   (
   Sum(advdep.Adv_Amt) AS Totals,
   Year([AdvDate]) AS [Year], Sum([advdep].[Adv_Amt]) AS Total
   FROM advdep INNER JOIN paymode ON advdep.AdvMode = paymode.PayID
   ) t
PIVOT paymode.Paymode;
```

It shows error in query syntax

Comment: Shouldn't that be a GROUP BY instead of PIVOT? Also don't think need subquery. Or maybe this https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-pivot-table-type/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL/MariaDB: create a pivot table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62711642/mysql-mariadb-create-a-pivot-table-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT YEAR(advdate) AS Year,
      SUM(adv_amt) AS Total,
      sum(CASE WHEN advmode='1' THEN adv_amt END) `CSH`,
      sum(CASE WHEN advmode='2' THEN adv_amt END) `CHQ`,
      sum(CASE WHEN advmode='3' THEN adv_amt END) `CRD`,
      sum(CASE WHEN advmode='4' THEN adv_amt END) `NEFT`,
      sum(CASE WHEN advmode='7' THEN adv_amt END) `UPI`
      
  FROM advdep
 GROUP BY YEAR(advdate);
```

Comment: our answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: The table is payment done by customers in various forms like card, cash, NEFT, cheque etc. The code makes a crosstab which gives yearly total amount paid and in what form the payment was done.  The original table is  like : Date, Amount Paid, Mode of payment, bill ID.  The output is : Yearly aggregate of total amount paid and sum of payment done via various modes. The total yearly sum = CSH + CRD +CHQ + NEFT + UPI